# how to set wpf form as windows form application mainform in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am very new in WPF.

I have created a form style in Wpf application.

I want set this WPF application formstyle as my windows form application form style.

How can i do it.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

The form image is 
[image]

Comment: would you post that formstyle as a screenshot so that we can suggest any ideas on how to implement that form style in winforms

Comment: ok please wait i will paste it

Comment: pratapchandra,i updated my question please check it

Comment: take a look at this link http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path  this will helps you to make rectangle and you can modify this depends on your requirement

Comment: can u say me how can i make my windows form border style Curved

Comment: see my answer on how to make a rounded corner winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the forms onpaint event and drawing the region there.  This allows  to use GDI+ with antialiasing and make it look much cleaner.

you can use this solution also [creating custom borders in winforms](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx)

The examples are found  at here:

http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=283&artID=7833
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=288178

Comment: its creating a circle i want a curve if it is possible can u please update your answer please

Comment: I am sorry I have updated links pls take a look at those ones

Comment: do you have c# links and could you paste it please because i just know c# not VB

Comment: those all are C# links except the last one and you can find  online converter by searching google to convert vb.net to C#